# cURL return generic error 500

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I try to create to create my `ExpressCheckout` but my code return me an error 500.

Here is the code :

```
$ch = curl_init($requete);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$resultat_paypal = curl_exec($ch);


if (!$resultat_paypal)
    {echo "<p>Erreur</p><p>".curl_error($ch)."</p>";}
else
{
    $liste_param_paypal = recup_param_paypal($resultat_paypal); 

    if ($liste_param_paypal['ACK'] == 'Success')
    {

        header("Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=".$liste_param_paypal['TOKEN']);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {echo "<p>Erreur de communication avec le serveur PayPal.<br />".$liste_param_paypal['L_SHORTMESSAGE0']."<br />".$liste_param_paypal['L_LONGMESSAGE0']."</p>";}
```

I also tried :

`curl_exec($ch) === false` instead `if (!$resultat_paypal)`

Comment: HTTP 500 means something went wrong on the server. Do you have access to any logs on the PayPal end that might shed some light on what's happening?

Comment: @Chris where can I found the logs ?

Comment: I don't know. That's what I'm asking you. You might need to contact PayPal support and ask them about this.

Comment: Customers don't have access to the PayPal logs, you need to contact them.

Comment: `webscr&com` should be `webscr?cmd`. `?` is used to separate the URL from the parameters, and `&` is used to separate parameters from each other.

Comment: @Barmar So i can't phone them because am Eurepean. Did you have solutions ?

Comment: I told you: fix that typo.

Comment: @Barmar it don't change. I still have the error 500.

Comment: I misread your code, that isn't the URL you're getting the 500 from. The problem is with `$requete`, but you haven't shown what's in that.

Comment: @Barmar I found the heck it's solved :D